# Asymptotic behaviour of a sequence of integrals

Tags: probability, integration, proof-explanation, asymptotics, sequence-of-function

Equation (37) on pg. 226 of "Birthday paradox, coupon collectors, caching algorithms and self-organizing search" by Flajolet, Gardier and Thimonier reads:
$$
E\{C_m\} = \int_0^{\infty}(1-\Theta_m(t)) dt, \quad \mathrm{where} \quad \Theta_m(t)=\prod_{i=1}^m (1-e^{-p_i t}).
$$
In fact they omit the subscript $m$ from $\Theta_m$, but as stackexchange user kimchi lover points out, $\Theta$ does indeed depend on $m$.
Here $m$ is a positive integer, and for all $i\in\{1, \ldots, m\}$, $p_i=\frac{1}{H_m i}$, where $H_m$ is the $m$-th harmonic number, $\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k}$. Thus $\{p_1, \ldots, p_m\}$ is a Zipf distribution.

The authors write (my subscript $m$)

"It can be proved that $\Theta_m(t)$ has a sharp transition from $0$ to
$1$ for $t$ around $m \log^2 m$. More precisely, quantity
\begin{equation}
F_m(x)=-\log \Theta_m(xm \log m H_m)
\end{equation}
is such that for fixed $x$ as $m \to \infty$, we have: $F_m(x) \to \infty$ if $x<1$ and $F_m(x) \to 0$
if $x \geq 1$.''

I can prove the latter fact (if I replace $x\geq1$ by $x>1$, which I think is enough for the intended purpose - see below), and stackexchange user kimchi lover has kindly provided a proof of the former fact, here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3577487/159855

I assume that by $xm \log m H_m$ the authors mean $xm(\log m)H_m$, and this is confirmed by kimchi lover's proof.
As a corollary, the authors state that
\begin{equation}
E(C_m) \sim m \log^2 m, \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where by $\log^2 m$, I assume they mean $(\log m)^2$.
Intuitively this makes sense (since $m(\log m)H_m$ is the area of a rectangle of width $m(\log m)H_m$ and height $1$, and since $H_m \sim \log m$), but let's try to prove it:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{m(\log m)H_m} \int_0^{\infty}(1-\Theta_m(t)) dt
&= \int_0^{\infty}(1-\Theta_m(xm(\log m)H_m)) dx \\
&= \int_0^{\infty}(1-e^{-F_m(x)}) dx.
\end{align}
Let $\epsilon \in (0,1)$. Then since the integrand is between $0$ and $1$ and is decreasing in $x$, we have
\begin{align}
1 \geq \int_0^1 (1-e^{-F_m(x)}) dx
& \geq \int_0^{1-\epsilon}(1-e^{-F_m(x)}) dx \\
& \geq \int_0^{1-\epsilon}(1-e^{-F_m(1-\epsilon)}) dx \\
&= (1-\epsilon)(1-e^{-F_m(1-\epsilon)}) \\
&> (1-\epsilon)^2
\end{align}
for sufficiently large $m$.
Therefore
\begin{equation}
(1-\epsilon)^2 + \int_1^{\infty}(1-e^{-F_m(x)}) dx \leq \frac{E(C_m)}{m(\log m)H_m} \leq 1 + \int_1^{\infty}(1-e^{-F_m(x)}) dx
\end{equation}
provided $m$ is large enough.
If $\int_1^{\infty}(1-e^{-F_m(x)}) dx$ were in $o(m)$ as $m \to \infty$, then since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, (1) would follow.
Can we use the fact that, for $x>1$, $F_m(x) \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$ to prove that $\int_1^{\infty}(1-e^{-F_m(x)}) dx$ is indeed $o(m)$ as $m \to \infty$ ?

**EDIT:**

I should have asked for the stronger condition, that $\int_1^{\infty}(1-e^{-F_m(x)}) dx$ is in $o(1)$ (not only in $o(m)$), which does indeed hold, as kimchi lover has shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show, as $m\to\infty$,  that the ratio $$\frac{\int_{m(\log m)^2}^\infty(1-\Theta_m(t))\,dt}{m(\log m)^2}\to 0.\tag1$$
This convergence follows from the inclusion-exclusion or Bonferonni estimate $$1-\Theta_m(t)\le\sum_{i=1}^m e^{-p_it}$$ which can be explicity integrated to yield  the estimate 
$$
\int_{m(\log m)^2}^\infty(1-\Theta_m(t))\,dt\le
\sum_{i=1}^m \frac {e^{-p_im(\log m)^2 }}{p_i}$$
$$=
\sum_{i=1}^m i H_m \exp\left(-\frac {m(\log m)^2}{iH_m} \right)\le
m^2 H_m \exp\left(-\frac {(\log m)^2}{H_m} \right)\tag2.
$$
Under the fiction that $H_m=\log m$ it is easy to check (1), since the exponential on the right side of (2) evaluates to $1/m$.   A correct argument, based on $H_m=\log m +\gamma +o(1)$, gives the same result: the exponential factor in (2) is $\sim c/m$ for some non-zero constant $c$, and on division by $m(\log m)^2$, the ratio in (1) tends to $0$.

This Flajolet et al. paper is a strenuous read!

Comment: Thank you so much kimchi lover ! You have bailed me out yet again. I greatly appreciate your comment that the paper is a strenuous read. Coming from you that is very reassuring. Would it have killed the authors to include the odd hint ?! I'm sorry that it took me so long to respond. Like everyone, I have been distracted for obvious reasons. I hope you and yours are safe and well. Many thanks once more.

Comment: And thank you!  About "would have killed..."  This paper is not a textbook exposition for beginners, and it covers a lot of ground, so the authors had to set a threshold for what to not explain.  I think they did a pretty good job: you were able to isolate particular questions that you needed help with, which is a good sign. That said, they might have suffered a bit from the "experts' syndrome" of not understanding how much other people don't understand.  This sometimes afflicts particularly deep and subtle researchers, who sometime don't really understand their own relative strength.

Comment: That seems very fair :) It was probably rude of me.